# How to translate 欢迎乘坐我们的出租车！

Tags: translation

欢迎乘坐我们的出租车！is an idiomatic Chinese sentence. When a passenger enters a taxi, the driver can use it as a greeting. By word-for-word translation,

> 欢迎: welcome (to)
>
> 乘坐: take
>
> 我们的: our
>
> 出租车: taxi

To make it a sentence: *Welcome to take our taxi!*. But from the English perspective, *Welcome to take our taxi!* is a wrong sentence. So, I have some difficulty to turn that Chinese sentence into English.

By the way, some cabs in Shanghai have a machine installed. When a customer enters the car, it will play the utterance: *Welcome to take our taxi!*. It just sounds ugly to an English native's ear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even though is not suitable, but how about "welcome aboard" ?

Comment: +1 Agree with Revol729, just use Welcome Aboard is enough

Comment: @dan Isn't it "Welcome to take *my* taxi"? Also you might find this reddit thread interesting https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/8nxxcm/is_welcome_to_take_my_taxi_grammatically_correct/ - one comment says: *However, American taxi drivers are often English Learners as well, so while it's not correct, it is potentially something you would hear from a friendly taxi driver.*

Comment: @user3306356 taxi cars are  owned by a company, hence it's *our taxi*.

Comment: Mainly about English

Comment: I don't know how to make it sound native and convey all the connotation. The meaning behind 欢迎乘坐我们的出租车 is "Thank you for taking our taxi, and we'll appreciate your next coming."

Comment: What's wrong by using the good old greeting :Good morning/afternoon/evening". 
Mainland China has a strange habit of making simple manner ridiculous.

Comment: Agree :) Not only for the manners, they like to use big words for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe:

"nice to meet you, welcome aboard"

if, said by machine, try

"welcome aboard of this XXX (company name) taxi"

have fun :)

Comment: "welcome aboard of ..." is not grammatically correct.

Comment: oops :)  it's derived from "welcome aboard of the pelican express" http://www.pelicanboattrips.com/dolphin.php?s=std